# Electric Potential from separating charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential, potential-energy

Say there are 2 charges, one of charge C, and the other with a charge of -2C. C=1.5*10^-6 C. Initially, they are right next to each other. I pull them apart to a distance of 15 cm.

So I can use the equation for potential energy to find the energy required to separate these charges. If I understand things correctly, this is also the work done on the charges, and the energy that would be released if i let go of the charges. But what about potential? How would I calculate the potential difference. Initially, the difference is 0, correct? But how would I figure out the potential after they are separated? I tried using the fact the potential is equal to potential energy per charge, but which charge would I divide by? Another equation for potential says that V=Ed. But which E field would I calculate? This would give me a different potential depending on the charge I pick. Shouldn't the potential for either charge be the same? Whether I pulled the C away from the 2C, or pull the 2C away from the C. Isn't that essentially the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Initially, they are right next to each other.
>   Initially, the difference is 0.

In the context of the question these are statement which cannot be dealt with.

If there is one isolated charge -2Q then the potential at a distance $r$ from that charge is $-\dfrac{2kQ}{r}$ with the zero of potential at infinity.
This is like going down a hill (potential well) in a gravitational field.

Bringing a charge of $+Q$ from infinity, where the potential energy of the two charges is zero up to a distance $x$ from charge $-2Q$ will result in the two charges having a potential energy of $-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{x}$.
The $+Q$ charge has rolled down the hill (potential well) and the potential energy of the two charges has decreased.

This is where you should realise that $x$ cannot equal 0 as in the expression for potential energy $x$ is the denominator.

Now you pull the charges apart to a separation $y$ with $y>x$.
The new potential energy of the two charges is $-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{y}$.
The potential energy has increased as it is less negative because the $+Q$ charge has had to out of the potential well.

The change in potential energy (final - initial) is $-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{y} -\left (-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{x}\right ) = \dfrac{k2Q^2}{x}-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{y}$ which will be positive as $y>x$.

In this example you should not use $E = \dfrac V d$ as the electric field is not uniform.
In fact you should be using $E = - \dfrac {dV}{dr}$
The potential due to the $-2Q$ charge was $-\dfrac{2kQ}{r}$ and this will give a value for the electric field due to the $-2Q$ charge of $E = -\dfrac{2kQ}{r^2}$.  The negative sign shows that the electric field is towards the $-2Q$ charge.

If I had started with the $+Q$ charge all alone then the potential at a distance $r$ is $+\dfrac{kQ}{r}$ and the electric field at this position is $+\dfrac{kQ}{r^2}$.

Now when one starts to move the $-2Q$ charge towards the $+Q$ charge the potential energy, $-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{y}$, and the change in potential energy, $\dfrac{k2Q^2}{x}-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{y}$, will be the same as before.

In terms of energy it does not matter which charge you move or indeed you can move them both.

**Later**

Consider the $+Q$ charge on its own.
At a point $X$, $x$ away from the charge, the potential is $\dfrac{kQ}{x}$ and at another point $Y$, $y$ away from the charge, the potential is $\dfrac{kQ}{y}$.
Then the potential of point $Y$ relative to point $X$ (the potential difference between points $X$ and $Y$ is  $\dfrac{kQ}{y} - \dfrac{kQ}{x}$.

Since potential difference $\times$ charge is the change in potential energy multiplying $\dfrac{kQ}{y} - \dfrac{kQ}{x}$ by $-2Q$ will give the change in potential energy.

Note that this is the same as found above $\dfrac{k2Q^2}{x}-\dfrac{k2Q^2}{y}$

Again you could start with the potential due to the $-2Q$ charge and work out the potential difference and hence the change in potential energy.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, yet I feel as if my original question has not been answered. I understand your analysis of the potential energy in this system, however, what of Potential difference?

Comment: @KSUwattcat In response to your question I have added to my answer.

Comment: So if I start with with -2Q charge, my potential difference would be much the same as starting with Q, but with a coefficient of 2 on each term. This would imply that the potential difference, if you start with one charge, would be different than starting with the other. Is this true?

Comment: If instead of the $+Q$ charge you had a $-2Q$ charge then the potential difference between $X$ and $Y$ will be different but then moving charge $+Q$ between those two points will result in the same change in potential energy of the two charges.

Comment: OK, this has provided me with much clarity. Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

> But what about potential?

Potential is concept best associated with a sum of single charge effects. In a space with a single charge at point 1, there is an electric field at all points other than the charge location.
$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q_1}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
 There is also a value of electric potential at all points other than the charge location. 
$$\phi=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q_1}{r}$$

$r$ is the distance from a charge to a point in space, and $\hat{r}$ is a unit vector pointing from the charge toward the point in space.

There is no force and there is no electric potential energy.

If I add a second charge at point 2, the E-field at that point is considered to remain unchanged for classical calculational purposes, and the potential remains unchanged (for classical calculational purposes). However, at all other points the total E-field and the electric potential have changed. At point 1, the second charge has produced a potential and an E-field, and at all other points the E-field is the vector sum of the E-fields of the charges, and the potential is the algebraic total of the individual potentials of the charges for those points.

The field of the second charge interacts with the first charge producing a force on the first charge, and simultaneously (not a reaction, but a pair force) the second charge interacts with the field of the first charge producing a force on the second charge. These two forces are equal and opposite (and you already know this, right?)

Adding the second charge also **adds** electric potential energy to the **system** of two charges. It adds$$ \Delta U=Q_2\phi_1(r_2)$$
where $r_2$ is the distance from $Q_1$ to $Q_2$.

Potential difference, or voltage, is simply the difference in total potential between two *points* in a space where charges exist.

Your statement $V=Ed$ is a big simplification which assumes that the E-field vector is constant between the two points which as distance $d$ apart. That assumption is definitely not true for two point charges.

So to talk about the potential difference between two charges is misleading.   The important thing is what happens to the potential energy of the system when charges move, and that depends on potential difference between the old location of a charge and the new location.

Comment: Although you accepted a different answer (and it is a good one), you can upvote others if they are also helpful.